# Replace part of string in columns names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, multiple-columns, rename

I have a issue with changing columns names. There is a part that I have to remove. Tables looks like below

```
Column.name_1  Column.name_2  Column.*.name_3  Column_name_4  Column_*_name_5
```

I wrote a line of code that changes dot and strix into underscore:

```
df_check.columns = df_check.columns.str.replace('.*.', '_')
```

But I get

```
Column_name_1  Column_name_2  Column___name_3  Column_name_4  Column___name_5
```

And I need below result with only one uderscore.

```
Column_name_1  Column_name_2  Column_name_3  Column_name_4  Column_name_5
```

Can you help me with this?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
df_check.columns = df_check.columns.str.replace(r'[.*_]+', '_', regex=True)
```

Output names:

```
['Column_name_1', 'Column_name_2', 'Column_name_3', 'Column_name_4', 'Column_name_5']
```